# How can I get all positions of a certain substring in a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, count, substring

We have a string:

```
$str = 'abc abc abc';
substr_count($str,'a') // gives 3
```

Is there any way to get an array containing all positions where the substring(In this example: `a`) occurs, for example:

```
[ 0 , 4 , 8 ]
```

Comment: [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) has an option for offset capture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and set the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag, e.g.

```
<?php

    $str = 'abc abc abc';
    preg_match_all("/a/", $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    print_r(array_column($m[0], 1));

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code block for finding the positions

```
<?php
$string = "abc abc abc";
$needle = "a";
$lastPos = 0;
$pos = array();

while(($lastPos = strpos($string, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $pos[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}
foreach ($pos as $value) {
    echo $value ."<br />";
}
```