# Can you enumerate all positions of a substring's co-occurence in bash

Tags: bash

tl;dr: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032746/how-can-i-get-all-positions-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-string) but in bash

I'm trying to write a code in bash that given a string and substring, returns all positions of the substring where it exists.

For example, if my string is `abcabcabc` and my substring is `ab`, I want it to return the values 1, 4, and 7 (or 0, 3, and 6 if zero-indexed).

I have this to start:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
read -p "Enter string: " string
read -p "Enter substring: " substring
expr index "$string" "$substring"
```

But this only returns the position of the first occurrence of the substring. How can I work around it to get all positions of all occurrences?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this information? Knowing that will inform the solution. String manipulation isn't bash's strong suit, but perhaps the higher level task you're trying to accomplish is?

Comment: @JohnKugelman This is more of an exercise for myself with bash, although I'd most likely apply it working with finding specific motifs in DNA/RNA sequences. That being said, I do realize it's easier to use BioPython for such an application. Was just wondering if it was entirely possible in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `expr index`. It searches for characters, not for substrings. From the [expr(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expr):

> ```
> index STRING CHARS
>     index in STRING where any CHARS is found, or 0
> ```

A manual loop is neither fast nor elegant, but it'll get the job done.

Explanation of syntax:

- `${#string}` is the length of `$string`.
- `${string:i:${#substring}}` extracts the substring at index `i` with the same length as `$substring`.

```
for ((i = 0; i <= ${#string} - ${#substring}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${string:i:${#substring}} == "$substring" ]]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

This will find overlapping substrings. If you don't want that then adjust `i` whenever a match is found:

```
for ((i = 0; i <= ${#string} - ${#substring}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${string:i:${#substring}} == "$substring" ]]; then
        echo "$i"
        ((i += ${#substring} - 1))
    fi
done
```